# Let's consider the metric space $\Bbb{Q}$ with the euclidian metric of $\Bbb{R}$

Tags: general-topology

Understanding the theorem:

Let's consider the metric space $\Bbb{Q}$ with the euclidian metric from $\Bbb{R}$.

Let $a,b\in$ $\Bbb{R}\setminus{\Bbb{Q}}$ with $a<b$ and $S=(a,b)\cap\Bbb{Q}$ . Prove that $S$ is closed and bounded in $\Bbb{Q}$, but not compact.

My question is why $S$ is not compact if Heine-Borel's theorem tells me that if a set  is closed and bounded then the set is compact.

Comment: Heine-Borel's theorem tells me that if a set is closed and bounded then the set is **connected** - you mean the set is compact.

Comment: The Heine-Borel theorem is about the topology on $R^n.$ However, note you are proving $S$ is compact in $\mathbb{Q}$, not in $\mathbb{R}$!

Comment: Please fix the typo. connected -> compact. Note that the Heine Borel theorem applies to $\mathbb{R}^n$. Note that $S$ is not complete, so there are Cauchy sequences that do not have a limit.

Comment: Yes! thank you, I thought  the same thing but I dont was not sure.

Comment: Why $S$ is closed, If I may ask? Take for instance $a=0$ and the sequence $1/n$.

Comment: @dmtri $a$ must be irrational, and so is $b$. Hence, $S$ may be written as $[a,b]\cap \mathbb Q$, which is closed in $\mathbb Q$ for the induced topology.

Comment: @Suzet, Sorrry you are right. I did not pay attention in the meaning in $\Bbb{Q}$ metric space.

Comment: Consider $d(x,y)=\min\{1,|x-y|\}$ as a metric on $\Bbb R$. Then $\Bbb R$ is closed and bounded. But this metric induces the same topology as the Euclidean metric, so $\Bbb R$ is not compact (or, if you prefer, cover $\Bbb R$ by intervals $(x-\frac14,x+\frac14)$, then there is no finite subcover). So even if the space is complete and connected, the Heine–Borel theorem doesn't necessarily work. Once you introduce the notion of *totally bounded*, then it works.

Answer (score 3):

Heine-Borel's theorem talks about subsets of $\mathbb{R}^n$ but you are dealing with a subset of $\mathbb{Q}$. While being bounded doesn't depend on the choice of the "big" space being closed does. For example $(-\sqrt{2}, \sqrt{2})\cap\mathbb{Q}$ is closed in $\mathbb{Q}$ but not in $\mathbb{R}$.

So back to your question. For any real number $r\in\mathbb{R}$ there exists a sequence $(q_n)\subseteq\mathbb{Q}$ convergent to $r$. Also if $a,b\in\mathbb{R}$, $a<b$ then there exists a irrational $z\in\mathbb{R}\backslash\mathbb{Q}$ such that $a<z<b$. These two facts together imply $(a,b)\cap\mathbb{Q}$ cannot be compact for any $a<b$.

Now your $S$ is obviously bounded. It is also closed because $(a,b)\cap\mathbb{Q}=[a,b]\cap\mathbb{Q}$ if $a,b$ are irrational.